# How to get Flux<T> from Mono<K> in Spring Reactive API?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I have two independent collections in NoSQL document db Photo and Property where Photo has propertyId parameter meaning that I can find all photos that belong to a given property like a house. Normally without reactive I would simply do:

```
Property property = ....
List<Photo> = photoService.findByPropertyId(property.getId());
```

Just two lines. How to do above in Reactive Programming when I have

```
`Mono<Property> and I want to find Flux<Photo>
```

without using block()?`  Assume aphotoService.findByPropertyId return List and in reactive case it returns Flux.

Comment: Are you looking for the `map` function on the `Mono` (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `flatMapMany`, which triggers an async processing from the `Mono`'s value which can emit multiple elements:

```
Flux<Photo> photoFlux = propertyMono
    .flatMapMany(prop -> photoService.findByPropertyId(prop.getId()));
```